# Simulation with Time of survival bootstrap using bsample and post commands

Tags: stata

I'm trying in Stata to make a simulation bootstrapping my population using `bsample`.

The dataset is `stan3` and my aim is to get time of survival percentiles (10 20 30 40 50). I know there could be other ways to do the same thing but I would like to understand why, even if my code seems to work, after cycling over the 20th percentile I get all the same results.

```
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r17/stan3.dta, clear
set trace on
tempname p
tempvar s i

postfile `p' int(rep) float(s i) using btsur, replace 
forval i=10(10)50 {                               // i are percentiles
    forval nsim = 1/100 {
        quietly bsample
        quietly sts gen `s'= s                   // estimates the chances of survival in the sample obtained by bootstraping
        quietly summarize _t if `s'<=(100-`i')/100, meanonly
        post `p' (`nsim') (`r(min)') (`i')       // i save r(min) because I want the lowest time possible where survival is 100-`i'
        drop `s'
    }
}
postclose `p'
use btsur,clear
browse in 80/250
```

Comment: You are each time around the loop after the first bootstrapping a sample from the previous bootstrapped sample, not from the original data. That is a puzzling choice and I suspect it's a bug in your code. That aside, I can't easily follow your procedure for percentile calculation. I would recommend direct use of `pctile`.  Further, the natural procedure would seem to be to take a bootstrap sample and then calculate wanted percentiles from that, not to take a different bootstrap sample for each percentile.

Comment: Hi Nick and thanks for your answer,
the idea was to estimates the confidence interval around each percentile (10 20 30 40 50) of survival time bootstraping. That's the reason behind that simulation. Above that your point is consistent. I'll explicit a step-by-step idea behind the code:
- we take the survival function
- we point to the 10 20 30 40 50 percentiles of survival time
- we bootstrap using bsample to generate the CI with 100 repetitions
- we choose r(min) because we want the lowest time possible where survival is 100-`i'

Comment: You can ask for results for several statistics at once. Looking at the help for `bootstrap` I see that the first example shows precisely that. Otherwise put, why not use `bootstrap` here?

Comment: Because there are situations where you can't export scalar/ecc that you have to use -post- commands and I would like to train myself:
https://github.com/tpmorris/TheRightWay

Comment: I know Tim Morris personally but I have not read that stuff. I doubt that Tim would sign up to what you seem to be doing, especially bootstrapping a bootstrapped sample. Sorry, but I think I need to disengage here, as your question keeps morphing and raises  too many general and specific issues.

Comment: @NickCox sorry Nick, I wouldn't intend to annoy you, I was just trying to explain myself better. Thanks for your precious feedback, I'll study more and I'll focus the trouble points.

Comment: I am not annoyed, and "sorry" flags an apology. I now doubt that I can say anything else that will help you, not least because I don't work with survival data and am not a medical statistician.  It's a limitation of every site, forum or mailing list that they work best with simple, specific questions. Once a question seems to be morphing into a complicated discussion you need an expert on the other end and/or some other kind of tuition, training or feedback.

Comment: Sure, I will look for my biostatistic professor's feedback or at least I will sudy to split the problem in smaller ones. I was apologizing becase I know the aim of lists/forums like this and It could be troublesome to solve an ussue with so much mess. Thanks again.